# Why is my code not asking for the user input on the for loop (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop, user-input

I can't get the user input in the for loop and I have no clue why. I am fairly new to java so please forgive my sloppiness. I posted my whole code because I do not know where the issue is at all.

```
    package grade.average.calculator;


import java.util.Scanner;
        
@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
public class GradeAverageCalculator {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       Scanner student = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
       String person;
            person = student.nextLine();
       Scanner muid = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your MUID: ");
       String id;
            id = muid.nextLine();
    }
    int grades[]= new int[3];
    int i;
    float total=0, avg;
    Scanner marks = new Scanner(System.in);
    {
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        System.out.print("Enter Grades of Subject"+(i+1)+":");
        grades[i] = marks.nextInt();
        total = total + grades[i];
}
    marks.close();
    avg = total/3;
```

Comment: Why are you creating multiple Scanner's based on System.in? You can use the same scanner for all of this. But grades and total should still be working.

Comment: Your indentation isn't indented consistently so it's very difficult to tell, but I think you have code outside of any method.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is outside of your main class.
It is not a reachable code, so it can't be executed.

So, the easiest:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner student = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        String person;
        person = student.nextLine();
        Scanner muid = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your MUID: ");
        String id;
        id = muid.nextLine();
        method();
    }

    public static void method() {
        int grades[] = new int[3];
        int i;
        float total = 0, avg;
        Scanner marks = new Scanner(System.in);

        {
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter Grades of Subject" + (i + 1) + ":");
                grades[i] = marks.nextInt();
                total = total + grades[i];
            }
            marks.close();
            avg = total / 3;
        }
    }
```